# Como puedo solicitar un token de autorización con Oauth2.0

Tags: c#, api

Buenas estoy desarrollando una app de consumo de apis en c# y necesito consumir una api con autorización oauth2.0 el problema es que no sé como hacerlo este es el código que he probado

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add($"Authorization", $"Bearer " + AuthorizationApi.GetBasicAuth());

                ConstantesModel constantes = new ConstantesModel();
                string apiBase = constantes.getApi("API_REP");
                string api = apiBas;


                var stringContent = new StringContent(data.mensaje, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(api, stringContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

dentro de esta misma función llamo a otra llamada GetBasicAuth() para obtener la autorización la cual es esta

```
 public static string GetBasicAuth()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                IniFile seccionLOG = new IniFile(@"C:/TTLKN/SET/SETTINGS/SettingsEnviaRC.ini", "API");
                ConsumeToken obj = new ConsumeToken();
                dynamic api_res = ConsumoApiToken.GetDataToken(client);
                string ACCESS_TOKEN = api_res.access_token;
                string TOKEN_NAME = seccionLOG.Read("TOKEN_NAME");
                string CLIENT_ID_API = seccionLOG.Read("CLIENT_ID_API");
                string API_USER = seccionLOG.Read("API_USER");
                string API_PASS = seccionLOG.Read("API_PASS");
                string credentials = ACCESS_TOKEN + ":" + TOKEN_NAME + ":" + CLIENT_ID_API + ":" + API_USER + ":" + API_PASS;
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
                string base64credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                return base64credentials;
            }
```

de acuerdo a la api que voy a consumir encesito un token de acceso, un nombre de token, cliente id, api user y api pass, todo eso le proporciono a la autorización para crear el token sin embargo no consigo salir del error 401 no autorizado, si alguien sabe como hacer esto se lo agradecería mucho.

Les comparto todo lo que necesita esta api para ser consumida como POST
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la API, ya revisaste que información necesita, revisaste su documentación?

Comment: Con una concesión de autorización debes(la aplicacion) solicita un access token al servidor de autorizaciones

Comment: la api es esa que llamo desde una variable "string apiBase =constantes.getApi("API_REP");" y de acuerdo a la doc que me entregaron sobre como consumirla necesita de un  access token, un token_name, client_id, username, y password que es lo que mando por parámetros en mi código

Comment: Este protocolo es el que se usa cuando te logas en en una web con el login de google por ejemplo.

Comment: Antes de que puedas consumir una api hay tres pasos anteriores, redirigir a la página de login, obtener el permiso, y solicitar el token

Comment: En este acaso  los pasos que me indicaron fueron solicitar un token de autorización a una api que lo hace, eso lo tengo listo y luego con ese mismo token lo envío como credenciales junto ocn los demas parámetros que especifiqué en mi código como oauth2.0 para poder obtener el token que me autorizará consumir la api, pero sin embargo solo obtengo un 401 de no autorizado, no sé si estaré pasando de manera incorrecta los parámetros que me piden para solicitar el token en oauth2

Comment: Mira esta información https://programacionymas.com/blog/protocolo-oauth-2

Comment: Es un protocolo de seguridad y funciona en conjunto...si un paso no esta bien hecho no te deja acceder...y unos tiempos(supongo)

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi deberia servirte, pero creo que te falta documentacion sobre la API que deseas consumir .

```
public async Task<string> GetBasicAuth()
    {
        string respuesta = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ACCESS_TOKEN + ":" + TOKEN_NAME + ":" + CLIENT_ID_API + ":" + API_USER + ":" + API_PASS);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "es-ES");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
            Uri url = new Uri("URL_ENDPOINT_DE_LA_API_DONDE_TE_VAS_A_AUTENTIFICAR", UriKind.Absolute);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(data.mensaje, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent );
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Aun no me ha funcionado pero edite mi pregunta agregando fotos de lo necesario para consumir la api si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradecería un montón

Comment: Cuando lo haces por POSTMAN te funciona bien ??

Comment: si funciona correctamente por postman

Comment: Entonces en tu pregunta describe : Parametros, Autorizacion, Cabeceras, Pre-Request Script, Test y Settings tal cual como lo haces en PostMan para apoyarte a crear la soliciitud